# C++ Choose a random object at runtime

Tags: c++

I want to choose a random class, and make an object of it at runtime (the classes I am choosing are derived from a base class). How do I accomplish that

Comment: No, you can't make array of defines.

Comment: Do `A`, `B` and `C` inherit from a common base class?

Comment: this is badly asked question. This is typical case of [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, they inherit from a common base class

Comment: @MarekR I am asking a general question, I am not asking a question based on my "attempted solution"

Comment: Read the link I've provided. You are asking how to fix you bad idea how to solve some problem and you didn't described what is your problem.

Comment: Randomly choose at compile time?

Comment: No idea what you are asking about. `#define` is a textual replacement instruction, what does it mean to make an 'array' of it?

Comment: @MarekR Have you read my question? The problem is I want to choose a random type, and create an object of that type

Comment: Can't you do something like `Base *ptr; switch (rand()%3) {case 0: ptr = new A; break; case 1: ptr = new B; break; case 2: ptr = new C;}`? (Or even better, using `unique_ptr`s instead of plain pointers.)

Comment: Rephrased my question since no one can understand it for some reason

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That is my solution right now, but I don't want to do that since if there are 20 classes, it gets ugly

Comment: @Poyr23 You are going to have *somewhere* that enumerates all your 20 classes. HolyBlackCat's switch puts it all in one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a factory function: each class should provide a static function of the same signature that returns a pointer to the base class.  Then, build an array of those factory functions which have the same signature, so you can randomly select.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

class CommonClass
{
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<CommonClass> (*FactoryFunction)(); // type for factory function
};

class A : public CommonClass
{
public:
    A() {};
    static std::shared_ptr<CommonClass> Create() { return std::make_shared<A>(); }
};

class B : public CommonClass
{
public:
    B() {};
    static std::shared_ptr<CommonClass> Create() { return std::make_shared<B>(); }
};


std::shared_ptr<CommonClass> CreateRandom()
{
    // Vector of factory functions, initialized once.
    static std::vector< CommonClass::FactoryFunction >  factories = 
        { &A::Create, &B::Create };

    std::random_device rd;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 1);

    // Generate random index, look up factory function, then call it
    return factories[dis(rd)]();
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<CommonClass> c(CreateRandom());
}
```

The commenter makes a good point.  Here's an alternate version of the top portion that uses CRTP to write the factory function once:

```
// Interface layer
class CommonClass
{
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<CommonClass> (*FactoryFunction)();
};

// CRTP layer.  Put any subclass implementation here that can be expressed
// as a compile-time expression of the type of the subclass.
template<class S>
class CommonClassImpl : public CommonClass
{
public:
    static std::shared_ptr<CommonClass> Create() { return std::make_shared<S>(); }
};


class A : public CommonClassImpl<A>
{
public:
    A() {};
};


class B : public CommonClassImpl<B>
{
public:
    B() {};
};
```

Comment: You can reduce the duplication by templating `CommonClass` over the subclass (the CRTP)